# how to send mail in php with image as body of the mail using PHP Mailer

Tags: php, email, sendmail, phpmailer

```
$message.="<img src='cf_logo.png'/>";
```

the above code does not show the image in php
I need to show the image as body of the message.Not an attachment.

Comment: make sure path is right

Comment: $message="<img src='cf_logo.pnp'>";   I gave like this only

Comment: i want to know path is right or not .. and the div or table in which you are sending mail why dont you use background image property of css

Comment: $message="<div class='logo' style='display: inline-block;font-size: 19px;font-weight: bold;'><img src='cf_logo.png'/></div>";The Path of the image is right. i have the file and image in the same folder.ok i ll try with background image property

Comment: $message.="<div style='background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url('cf_logo.png') repeat-x scroll 0 0;width: 16px;'>image</div>";i gave like this . but still it does not displayed in mail

Comment: As others have said already, that path **will not work**. It needs to be an absolute URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->isSMTP(); // send via SMTP

//Enable SMTP debugging
// 0 = off (for production use)
// 1 = client messages
// 2 = client and server messages
//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->Host = $host; //SMTP server
$mail->Port = $port; //set the SMTP port; 587 for TLS
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail

if (strlen($username)) {
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = $username;
    $mail->Password = $password;
} else {
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false;
}

$mail->From = $from; // FROM EMAIL
$mail->FromName = $fromName; // FROM NAME
$mail->addAddress($to);
$mail->addReplyTo($from);

$mail->IsHTML($html);

$mail->Subject = $subject; // YOUR SUBJECT
$mail->Body = $message; // YOUR BODY
$mail->addAttachment($attachment); // YOUR ATTACHMENT FILE PATH

if ($mail->send()) {
    echo "Message Sent";exit;
} else {
    echo "Message Not Sent<br>";
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;exit;
}
```

**Note:** You need to include php mailer class.

Comment: i included the php mailer class. i dont want the logo as attachment . i want to be part of the meaasage as image

Comment: @MeenatchiP you can set that image with image tag in your $message. just make sure that image path is correct which should not be relative you have to set absolute file path i.e http://yoursite/folder/image.jpg

Comment: I gave the entire path with my site name .the image is displayed in gmail.Thanks.But in outlook it doesnot show the image .

Answer (score 0):

You need the full path:

```
 <img src='add your domain here'/cf_logo.png>
```

Comment: i gave the full path .In gmail the image is displayed. but in outlook and thunderbird it doesnot work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it might work., Use http:// in the front of your image url like this

http://yoursite/folder/image.jpg